# I want to redirect subdomain.domain1.com to domain2.com/directory using DNS

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I own 2 domain names "domain1.com" and "domain2.com", I want to redirect subdomain.domain1.com to domain2.com/directory using DNS (preferably). Can anyone assist (I am an amateur at domain management)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the is not possible with pure DNS.

DNS is only there (in case of A/AAAA/CNAME records) to take a domain name (a.b.c.domain.com) and return you the ip address (111.222.111.222).

Some DNS providers offer "redirect" but the most reliable way is if you configure "a.b.domain.com" on your server and sind a redirect request to the client.

One way is to do it with .htaccess like:

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain1\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain2\.com\/directory" [R=301,L]
```

(Note, the .htaccess sample is not tested, watch out for regex typos)